# hosting django website on google cloud compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to host a website on google cloud compute engine's virtual machine instance.

I am a developer, I ran wamp server locally for testing php applications, and python's manage.py runserver for running python webserver.And also installed Apached webserver on my local ubuntu machine for testing purpose.

I have reserved a static external ip for my instance.

please give me some advice on hosting django website on virtual machine instance

I have no experience in hosting on my own server for public facing websites
My virtual machine os is Debian based .

Answer (score 0):

There are [four main options](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/#hosting_platforms) for deploying Django on Google Cloud Platform. The recommended options being the Google App Engine, however since you are interested in developing Django apps on Google Compute Instance, you take advantage of deploying with the [Google Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/bitnami-launchpad/djangostack?q=django) to deploy Django Certified by Bitnami. This will create a new Django deployment with,

> Django, Git, Apache, MySQL, Node.js, OpenSSL, PostgreSQL, Python, SQLite.

And since you are new to deploying Django, you may also want to review writing your first Django app, part 1 [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/).

Answer (score -1):

I've recently created a tutorial: [Deploying Django to Google Cloud Platform - Compute Engine](https://www.sunnyville.ai/deploying-django-google-cloud-platform-compute-engine/). I think this may be what you are looking for.